# Virtual method getting called instead of the override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have four classes, `Event` and `Action` which are both base classes, and then I have two child classes `Create : Event` and `MoveTo : Action`.

`Event` contains a list of `Action` instances, and when `Trigger()` is called in the child `Create` it calls `Event.Trigger()`, which loops over the list of actions, and calls `Action.Run()` on each action which calls `Called()`.

The Issue I am having is the `virtual` method is getting called and not the `override` method inside of `MoveTo`.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Event : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] public List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

  protected void Trigger() {
    foreach (Action action in actions) {
      action.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

Event

```
public class Create : Event {
  void Start() {
    Trigger();
  }
}
```

Action

```
[Serializable]
public class Action {
  public virtual void Called() {
    Debug.Log("Virtual");
  }

  public void Run() {
    Called();
  }
}
```

MoveTo

```
public class MoveTo : Action {
  public override void Called() {
    Debug.Log("Called");
  }
}
```

I am adding the `MoveTo` action to the event list from the Unity Editor onto a prefab. I am not sure how unity handles these at runtime, does in initialize them or do I? That I am not sure about. That is what might be causing my issue...

```
private Event GetCurrentEvent(){}

void AddActionCallback(Type actionType) {
  // actionType is MoveTo
  var prefab = GetCurrentPrefabItem().Value;
  var evt = GetCurrentEvent();
  evt.actions.Add((Action)Activator.CreateInstance(actionType));
  Undo.RecordObject(prefab.gameObject, "Added actions");
  PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications(prefab.gameObject);
}
```

Here is what it looks like before I run the game. It shows `MoveTo`, the button in the red column shows the action using `action.GetType().Name`. This is the name before I run the game:

[image: before]

After I run the game the button now looks like this:

[image: after]

When running:

```
evt.actions.Add((Action)Activator.CreateInstance(actionType));
```

The editor displays **Type mismatch** even when the output of `actionType` and `Activator.CreateInstance(actionType)` is `MoveTo`:

[image: type mismatch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Unity does not support built-in polymorphic serialization](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/serialization-of-polymorphic-dat).

When you save the prefab, it serializes the List as a list of pure `Action`s, and erases any information that only the child class `MoveTo` has.

From the Unity [docs on serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html):

> ## No support for polymorphism
>
> If you have a `public Animal[] animals` and
>   you put in an instance of a`Dog`, a `Cat` and a `Giraffe`, after
>   serialization, you have three instances of `Animal`.
>
> One way to deal with this limitation is to realize that it only
>   applies to custom classes, which get serialized inline. References to
>   other `UnityEngine.Objects` get serialized as actual references, and for
>   those, polymorphism does actually work. You would make a
>   `ScriptableObject` derived class or another `MonoBehaviour` derived class,
>   and reference that. The downside of this is that you need to store
>   that `Monobehaviour` or `scriptable` object somewhere, and that you cannot
>   serialize it inline efficiently.
>
> The reason for these limitations is that one of the core foundations
>   of the serialization system is that the layout of the datastream for
>   an object is known ahead of time; it depends on the types of the
>   fields of the class, rather than what happens to be stored inside the
>   fields.

This is why its class shows up as an `Action`.

However, it can't serialize as an `Action` [because](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html):

> ## How to ensure a custom class can be serialized
>
> Ensure it:
>
> - Has the Serializable attribute
> - **Is not abstract**
> - Is not static
> - Is not generic, though it may inherit from a generic class

`Action` is an abstract class, so it won't even serialize partially properly. I assume this is the root cause of the `Type Mismatch` problem, as Unity is struggling to deserialize something that is unsupported.

In short, if you want to serialize data in `MoveTo`, you'll need to have a `[SerializeField]` `List<MoveTo>` in order to not lose the information, or you can have Action inherit from `ScriptableObject`, which brings its own problems.

Comment: Based on the first paragraph of the quote, that is exactly what I am seeing. Looks like I will have to find another way to do what I want.