# Type mismatch when adding item to list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have four classes, three are within a namespace the other is not (If that matters). When the `OnGUI` is called and the `if` evaluates to `true`, an item is supposed to be added to the `actions` list. It attempts to add it, but I get a `Type mismatch` in my Unity Editor. I can not seem to figure out why.

```
namespace Bootstrap {
  public class Action : ScriptableObject  {}
  public class JumpTo : Action {}

  public class Event : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
  }
}

public class BootstrapEditor: EditorWindow {
  void OnGUI() {
    if(/* button click */){
      AddItem(typeof(JumpTo));
    }
  }

  void AddItem(Type actionType) {
    Bootstrap.Event evt = GetCurrentEvent();
    Debug.Log(actionType);
    Debug.Log(evt.actions);
    evt.actions.Add((Bootstrap.Action)Activator.CreateInstance(actionType));
  }
}
```

[image: type mismatch]
[image: console output]

Comment: Are you sure `Action` isn't conflicting with `System.Action`?

Comment: I changed it to `MyAction` and still same thing...

Comment: check that, have you tried putting bootstrapeditor in the same namespace, might clear up any conflict

Comment: I just tried, and same results.

Comment: What does Activator.CreateInstance return? Why does it need to be cast into an Action?

Comment: @CaTs because it returns `object` and you have to cast to the appropriate type

Comment: What's the full exception you get?

Comment: I don't get one.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653400/virtual-method-getting-called-instead-of-the-override and my answer there addresses this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/52657248/1092820

Comment: Its because Unity creates the editor GUI based on the property's type declaration, not based on the property's value.  You should be able to make a custom editor GUI for it, but its going to be pretty involved if you want it to be polymorphic.